# How do I become better at using blender?

Tags: workflow

I've started using blender 2.82 for almost 3 months. I've pretty much learned the basics of its interface however I'm still struggling to pull off good 3d art. I feel that my skills are not that good and pretty lost in direction. I was wondering if anyone has any good advice or tutorials that have helped them improve their blender skills? I really want to become good using this program but I feel so dependent on following tutorials and copying what they are doing but not actually understanding what they are doing.

Comment: Related: [Should I just quit Blender when after weeksof watching tutorials I cannot model anything?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/126822/78972)

Comment: The  [link posted in my answer to that one](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10000-hour-rule-wrong-really-master-skill/)  is well worth a read.

Answer (score 5):

First, try to think in terms beyond "good" and "bad" (*good 3d art, good skills, good advice, become better...*), a world of possibilities will open for you.

Don't follow tutorials blindly, stop wasting your life with them, most of them are crap, or made by want-to-be-entertainers who ramble but don't explain the tools, or the main concepts.

There is a manual for blender, use it! (yes, reading is still a great source of information). If you still insist on watching videos, then read about the tool you don't understand.

Set yourself a goal, a project that you want to do, and do it. Then do another.

Don't be afraid to fail, and fail again and keep failing until you find solutions. You will learn more from your own mistakes than following videos.

Start with the basic in small steps, until you reach a point where you don't know how to proceed, then ask specific questions on this site or others.

Comment: Best answer *ever* for this kind of question.

Comment: For example i want to do a specific style of 3d art but cant find a way of how to do it in blender. How would i find out? also do you know any good books i could from?

Comment: @Mr_Shoryuken start here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender and for new questions **use the "Ask Question" link** at the top of the page, not the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me improve was using other artists drawings as references. Previously i would draw my character and then model it from my own drawing and it would always turn out pretty badly. Find some artworks from other artists that you like, instead of drawing your own or not using any reference at all, and try recreating them in 3d.