# What is the most effective technique for modeling?

Tags: modeling

I've been using subdivision on a cube when I model, but the problem I have with this technique is that I'm restricted to only working with the amount of faces that the subdivided cube has.

Is there a more effective way to create more complex models or do I just need to practice more?

Comment: There isn't a best techinque for model everything. It depends on what are you tring to model (organic modeling? hard surface? a car? a house? a charcter?...), why (the scope: static model? deformable? animatable? breakable?...), how (artistical and technicals requirements). That's said, you'll probably have to combine multiple techniques to get the best result.

Comment: Admittedly I'm interested in modeling a lot of things, I just don't know how I'm meant to go around modeling a building or a hat?? Objects with a lot of curves and extruded parts

Comment: We can't answer such a broad question. If you look on TY for: how to model a building/hat in blender, you'll see plenty of different approaches. There are too many factors to consider. Maybe you can pick 1 object that you want to model, post some picture of your goal, give a thought on the scope and the topology, describe your struggle with the tools you are currently using.... then we can provide some help.

Comment: I'll check out the TY thing, thank you

Comment: The **Most Effective** technique is the one that works for you, and your particular needs.

Comment: I meant YT, sorry... You Tube, I'm sure you knew it..

Comment: Read  [How do I become better at using blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181997/how-do-i-become-better-at-using-blender/182014#182014)

Answer (score 2):

To define what is the most effective 3d modeling technic, all the know technics should be evaluated in several factors, such as:

1. Time demanded
2. Computational cost
3. Quality
4. Practicality

And be considered for all different artists, computer configurations, type of scenarios, and even consider if the technic can be incorporated in a production pipeline among other artists. So, it is impossible to answer your question accurately.

**BUT**

To help you discover more about the various techniques (or styles) to do a 3D model in a DCC software such as Blender. I would suggest you watch this video from [Gleb Alexandrov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeHasEMCzcc) as a good start.

> Is there a more effective way to create more complex models or do I just need to practice more?

Also, as referred to in other comments, the modeling technic depends on what you are modeling, so maybe there is a better way to modeling, maybe not. But it is very common that along the process you discover ways to speed up or improve your knowledge to do 3D models.

And about practice, I guess the only person who can answer that is your employer or your clients. Because even if you have been modeling for 10 years, there are always new technics that you actually never practice. So it depends a lot on your expectations and demands.

Do your best, enjoy the process and stay curious.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just add a lot more faces to work with, an easy way to do that is to add a subdivision modifier, pump it up to however many subdivides you want, then apply the modifier. This is a quick way to turn a few polygons into hundreds, or thousands. However, it's not usually the best way to model, because it can slow down your computer quite a bit and your render times.

In my opinion, the best models are elegant - simple models with just enough faces to get the job done. Using loop cuts and subdivides and other tools to add geometry just where it's needed. But there is no right or wrong way to model.

Comment: I'll have to keep note of that. Thanks!